# Matrix of linear transformation format $(m,n)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a problem with doing an exercise in construction of a matrix by a given linear transformation.
So I understand ex. $f(x,y) = (2x, -y)$
is \begin{bmatrix}     
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
transform with this:

\begin{bmatrix}     
        2x\\
        -y\\
        \end{bmatrix}
results this:
\begin{bmatrix}     
        2 & 0\\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

but now I have something like this:
"In format $(m,n)$, matrix of linear transformation

1. $h(x) = (5x, x)$ is $(0,1), (1,0), (2,1)$
2. $f(x,y,z) = x + 2y$ is $(2,2),(2,1),(1,3)$
3. $g(x,y,z) = (x,z)$ is $(2,3), (3,2), (2,2)$
4. $s(x,y) = x + y$ is $(2,1), (1,2), (1,1)$

The task is to circle the correct one, how should I go about finding out which one is correct?

Comment: Is this how the question was written? Regards.

Comment: What's $(m,n)$?

Comment: This is exactly what it's written, and this was a question from the last year test.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking you for the *dimension* of the linear transformation.

What is the size of the output vector? That is the first number $m$.
How many input variables are there? That is the second number $n$.

For example $h(x)=(5x,x)$ produces a vector of dimension $2$, and takes in a single number $x$. Therefore the dimension of the transformation is $2\times 1$.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I didn't really understood the question, so 1)(2,1)   2)(1,3)  3) (2,3)  4) (1,2)